# Postgresql regular expression to get matches phone number prefix

Tags: regex, postgresql, phone-number

I have 2 tables, 1 for checking the phone number's type(Fixed or Mobile), another one is master data.
Data in **phone_number** table look like this:

```
number_prefix | type_number
----------------------------
84            | Fixed
84912         | Mobile
84917         | Mobile
...
```

And in **call_record** data like this:

```
cus_number    | billsec
------------------------
84912789645   | 48
8444984356    | 124
...
```

I want to have the customer number with type of their number on my query, then, I'm using JOIN/ON and regular expression as the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM call_record as cr
JOIN phone_number as pn ON cr.cus_number ~ ('^' || pn.number_prefix)
```

But the result of the number '84912789645' returns 2 records because that number the matched with '84' and '84912'.

```
cus_number    | billsec | prefix_number | type_number
-----------------------------------------------------
84912789645   | 48      | 84912         | Mobile
84912789645   | 48      | 84            | Fixed
...
```

It's wrong because that number is Mobile. In this case, how can I get the matches result(only Mobile) in my query?

Thank you.

=========================================================================

**Update**. I have the solution for this issue. I used subquery in condition to get the matches number_prefix.

```
SELECT *
FROM phone_number pn, call_record cr
WHERE pn.number_prefix = (
    SELECT number_prefix 
    FROM phone_number, call_record 
    WHERE (cr.customer_number ~ ('^' || number_prefix))
    ORDER BY number_prefix DESC 
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Thanks guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For postgresql 9.3

```
SELECT *
FROM
 call_record as cr
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (
        select * from phone_number
        where cr.cus_number ~ ('^' || number_prefix)
        ORDER BY number_prefix DESC
        LIMIT 1
  ) phone_number ON TRUE;
```

Comment: It may be faster to do a `DISTINCT ON (...)` after a full join.

Comment: A good answer is more than just the code.  Please explain the code as well.

Comment: We select only best match (the longest) by DESC sorting and limit to 1.

Comment: One more solution without join but only with one row:
SELECT *,(select type_number from phone_number where call_record.cus_number ~ ('^' || number_prefix) ORDER BY number_prefix DESC
        LIMIT 1) as type_number
) FROM call_record;

Comment: yeah, it similar with mine. I haven't test your solution but I think it's work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the prefixes for the fixed lines. In Vietnam mobile numbers may start with 84912 or 84917, but fixed lines start with 841, 842, 843, etc. 84 is the country code, not a full prefix.